# XSLT repeat parent node with child node

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to repeat the parent node in the same row as the child node. I have the data that is used to create the report, the current style sheet, and what I would like the out put to look like. I have not been able to figure out a solution. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thank you for your help its greatly appreciated.

Data

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <Result>
          <Item type="Part">
            <description>AML test</description>
            <id keyed_name="E008643" type="Part">57022FEA23B54493B691386368F5DFBB</id>
            <major_rev>1</major_rev>
            <name>9.6 Parts</name>
            <item_number>E008643</item_number>
            <Relationships>
              <Item type="Part AML">
                <related_id type="Manufacturer Part">
                  <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                    <item_number>1804</item_number>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <state>Preliminary</state>
              </Item>
              <Item type="Part AML">
                <related_id>
                  <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                    <item_number>JNED</item_number>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <state>Preliminary</state>
              </Item>
              <Item type="Part BOM">
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <related_id keyed_name="E000371" type="Part">
                  <Item type="Part">
                    <description>Part 1</description>
                    <name>0</name>
                    <item_number>E000371</item_number>
                    <Relationships>
                      <Item type="Part AML">
                        <related_id type="Manufacturer Part">
                          <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                            <manufacturer keyed_name="Speer" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                            <item_number>RK7D</item_number>
                          </Item>
                        </related_id>
                        <state>Preliminary</state>
                      </Item>
                      <Item type="Part AML">
                        <related_id type="Manufacturer Part">
                          <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                            <manufacturer keyed_name="Ven" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                            <item_number>CR00T</item_number>
                          </Item>
                        </related_id>
                        <state>Preliminary</state>
                      </Item>
                      <Item type="Part AML">
                        <related_id type="Manufacturer Part">
                          <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                            <manufacturer keyed_name="Sonic" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                            <item_number>ERJ</item_number>
                          </Item>
                        </related_id>
                        <state>Preliminary</state>
                      </Item>
                      <Item type="Part AML">
                        <related_id type="Manufacturer Part">
                          <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                            <manufacturer keyed_name="Comp" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                            <item_number>NRCF</item_number>
                          </Item>
                        </related_id>
                        <state>Preliminary</state>
                      </Item>
                      <Item type="Part AML">
                        <related_id type="Manufacturer Part">
                          <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                            <manufacturer keyed_name="Ya" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                            <item_number>RC0L</item_number>
                          </Item>
                        </related_id>
                        <state>Preliminary</state>
                      </Item>
                    </Relationships>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <sort_order>128</sort_order>
              </Item>
              <Item type="Part BOM">
                <quantity>30</quantity>
                <related_id keyed_name="E001163" type="Part">
                  <Item type="Part">
                    <description>Part 2</description>
                    <name>82</name>
                    <item_number>E001163</item_number>
                    <Relationships>
                      <Item type="Part AML">
                        <related_id keyed_name="ECH-U1C822GX5" type="Manufacturer Part">
                          <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                            <manufacturer keyed_name="Sonic" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                            <item_number>E2GX5</item_number>
                          </Item>
                        </related_id>
                        <state>Preliminary</state>
                      </Item>
                      <Item type="Part AML">
                        <related_id type="Manufacturer Part">
                          <Item type="Manufacturer Part">
                            <manufacturer keyed_name="Sonic" type="Manufacturer"></manufacturer>
                            <item_number>EGX5</item_number>
                          </Item>
                        </related_id>
                        <source_id keyed_name="E001163" type="Part"></source_id>
                        <state>Preliminary</state>
                      </Item>
                    </Relationships>
                  </Item>
                </related_id>
                <sort_order>256</sort_order>
              </Item>
             </Relationships>
          </Item>
        </Result>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Current Style Sheet

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:aras="http://www.aras-corp.com">
      <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <head>
       </head>
          <style type="text/css" userData="Global">
    .cellSolid {text-align:center;border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-right:1px #000000 solid;border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;border-left:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidTopRight {border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-right:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidTopLeft {border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-left:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidRightBottom {border-right:1px #000000 solid;border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;font-family:helvetica;font-size:8pt;}
    .cellSolidBottomLeft {border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;border-left:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidTop {border-top:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidRight {border-right:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidBottom {border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidLeft {border-left:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellDashed {border-top:1px #666666 dashed;border-right:1px #666666 dashed;border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;border-left:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedTopRight {border-top:1px #666666 dashed;border-right:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedTopLeft {border-top:1px #666666 dashed;border-left:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedBottomRight {border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;border-right:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedBottomLeft {border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;border-left:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedTop {border-top:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedRight {border-right:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedBottom {border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedLeft {border-left:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellHeader {background-color:#CCCCCC;border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-right:1px #000000 solid;border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;padding:2px;text-align:center;text-transform:capitalize;text-align:center;font-family:helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:8pt;}
    .cellTitle {border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-right:1px #000000 solid;border-left:1px #000000 solid;padding:2px;text-align:center;text-transform:capitalize;text-align:center;font-family:helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:8pt;}
    table  {empty-cells:show; border-collapse:collapse;}
    td.noBorder {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border-width:0;}
       </style>
          <body topmargin="50" leftmargin="50">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td width="150" uniqueID="ms__id11"></td>
                <td width="250" uniqueID="ms__id12"></td>
                <td width="200" uniqueID="ms__id13"></td>
         </tr>
              <tr valign="top">
                <td align="left" uniqueID="ms__id14" colspan="3">
                  <img src="../images/Logos/CooperPowerSystems.gif" height="60"></img>
          </td>
         </tr>
              <tr valign="bottom">
                <td class="noBorder" colspan="13" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:15pt;color:#DA1943;padding:2px;" align="left" uniqueID="ms__id15">AML Quantity Report -              <xsl:value-of select="//Item/name"></xsl:value-of> Rev              <xsl:value-of select="//Item/major_rev"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
                <td class="noBorder" colspan="4" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:10pt;padding:2px;" align="right" uniqueID="ms__id16">Generated on:              <script>function m00(r, n){r += ""; if (!n) n = 2; while(r.length &lt; n){r = "0" + r;} return r;} var dt = new Date(); var a = top.opener.top.aras; if (a){var s = m00(dt.getUTCFullYear(),4)+"-"+m00((dt.getUTCMonth()+1))+"-"+m00(dt.getUTCDate())+"T"+m00(dt.getUTCHours())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCMinutes())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCSeconds())+"+0000"; s = a.convertToNeutral(s, "date", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"); s = a.convertFromNeutral(s, "date", "short_date"); document.write(s);}</script>
                </td>
         </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="cellHeader" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" uniqueID="ms__id17">Part Number</td>
                <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id18">Name</td>
                <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id32">Description</td>
                <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id19">Calculated Quantity</td>
                <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id20">AML Status</td>
                <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id21">Manufacturer</td>
                <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id22">Manufacturer Part</td>
         </tr>
              <xsl:call-template name="main"></xsl:call-template>
        </table>
       </body>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
          <script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script>
        </html>
     </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:variable name="products"><!-- generate appropriate product for every item-->
          <xsl:call-template name="Unique"></xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Item//Item[@type='Part']">
          <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"></xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="part_number">
            <xsl:value-of select="item_number"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:if test="item_number='' or not(item_number)">
              <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="part_name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:if test="name='' or not(name)">
              <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="part_description">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:if test="description='' or not(description)">
              <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="is_first" select="count(ancestor::Item[@type='Part' and @id=string($id)] | preceding::Item[@type='Part' and @id=string($id)])"></xsl:variable>
          <xsl:if test="$is_first = 0">
            <xsl:variable name="sum_of_products" select="sum(msxsl:node-set($products)/product_for_item[item_id = $id]/product)"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="draw_row_for_item">
              <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id"></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="sum_of_products" select="$sum_of_products"></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="part_number" select="$part_number"></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="part_name" select="$part_name"></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="part_description" select="$part_description"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
     <!-- Draw rows of table-->
      <xsl:template name="draw_row_for_item">
        <xsl:param name="id"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="sum_of_products"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="part_number"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="part_name"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="part_description"></xsl:param>
        <tr>
          <xsl:variable name="rowCount">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="count(Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'])=0">1</xsl:when>          <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'])"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
          <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">
            <xsl:value-of select="$part_number"></xsl:value-of>
       </td>
          <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">
            <xsl:value-of select="$part_name"></xsl:value-of>
       </td>
          <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">
            <xsl:value-of select="$part_description"></xsl:value-of>
       </td>
          <td rowspan="{$rowCount}" class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id25">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum_of_products"></xsl:value-of>
       </td>
          <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id26">
            <xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'][1]/state"></xsl:value-of>
       </td>
          <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id27">
            <xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'][1]/related_id/Item/manufacturer/@keyed_name"></xsl:value-of>
       </td>
          <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id28">
            <xsl:value-of select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'][1]/related_id/Item/item_number"></xsl:value-of>
       </td>
      </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML'][position()!=1]"></xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:template>
     <!--use unique id and calculate quantity for item in current chain-->
      <xsl:template name="Unique">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Item[@type='Part']">
          <xsl:variable name="cur_id" select="@id"></xsl:variable>
          <xsl:if test="not(count(descendant::Item[@type='Part' and @id=string($cur_id)]))">
            <product_for_item>
              <item_id>
                <xsl:value-of select="$cur_id"></xsl:value-of>
              </item_id>
              <product>
                <xsl:variable name="quantity" select="../../quantity"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="string($quantity) = ''">0</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates mode="product_of_quantity" select="../..">
                      <xsl:with-param name="product_of_chain" select="$quantity"></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
             </product>
            </product_for_item>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
     <!--calculate product of quantities for item in its chain -->
      <xsl:template mode="product_of_quantity" match="Item[@type='Part BOM']">
        <xsl:param name="product_of_chain"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:choose><!-- If current Part BOM at the top of the current chain -->
          <xsl:when test="not(count(ancestor::Item[@type='Part BOM']))">
            <xsl:value-of select="number($product_of_chain)"></xsl:value-of>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise><!-- Get the quantity of the next relationship Part BOM and apply recursion again for it-->
            <xsl:variable name="quantity" select="../../../../quantity"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="product_of_quantity" select="../../../..">
              <xsl:with-param name="product_of_chain" select="number($quantity)*number($product_of_chain)"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="Item[@type='Part AML']">
        <tr>
          <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">
            <xsl:value-of select="state"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
          <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">
            <xsl:value-of select="related_id/Item/manufacturer/@keyed_name"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
          <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id31">
            <xsl:value-of select="related_id/Item/item_number"></xsl:value-of>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Preferred Output

```
    <html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:aras="http://www.aras-corp.com">
      <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
      </head>
      <style type="text/css" userData="Global">
    .cellSolid {text-align:center;border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-right:1px #000000 solid;border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;border-left:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidTopRight {border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-right:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidTopLeft {border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-left:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidRightBottom {border-right:1px #000000 solid;border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;font-family:helvetica;font-size:8pt;}
    .cellSolidBottomLeft {border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;border-left:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidTop {border-top:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidRight {border-right:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidBottom {border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellSolidLeft {border-left:1px #000000 solid;}
    .cellDashed {border-top:1px #666666 dashed;border-right:1px #666666 dashed;border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;border-left:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedTopRight {border-top:1px #666666 dashed;border-right:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedTopLeft {border-top:1px #666666 dashed;border-left:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedBottomRight {border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;border-right:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedBottomLeft {border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;border-left:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedTop {border-top:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedRight {border-right:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedBottom {border-bottom:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellDashedLeft {border-left:1px #666666 dashed;}
    .cellHeader {background-color:#CCCCCC;border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-right:1px #000000 solid;border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;padding:2px;text-align:center;text-transform:capitalize;text-align:center;font-family:helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:8pt;}
    .cellTitle {border-top:1px #000000 solid;border-right:1px #000000 solid;border-left:1px #000000 solid;padding:2px;text-align:center;text-transform:capitalize;text-align:center;font-family:helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:8pt;}
    table  {empty-cells:show; border-collapse:collapse;}
    td.noBorder {font-family:helvetica; font-size:8pt;  padding:2px; border-width:0;}
       </style>
      <body topmargin="50" leftmargin="50">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="150" uniqueID="ms__id11"></td>
            <td width="250" uniqueID="ms__id12"></td>
            <td width="200" uniqueID="ms__id13"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top">
            <td align="left" uniqueID="ms__id14" colspan="3"><img src="../images/Logos/CooperPowerSystems.gif" height="60"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="bottom">
            <td class="noBorder" colspan="13" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:15pt;color:#DA1943;padding:2px;" align="left" uniqueID="ms__id15">AML Quantity Report -              9.6 Parts Rev              1</td>
            <td class="noBorder" colspan="4" style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:10pt;padding:2px;" align="right" uniqueID="ms__id16">Generated on:              <script>function m00(r, n){r += ""; if (!n) n = 2; while(r.length < n){r = "0" + r;} return r;} var dt = new Date(); var a = top.opener.top.aras; if (a){var s = m00(dt.getUTCFullYear(),4)+"-"+m00((dt.getUTCMonth()+1))+"-"+m00(dt.getUTCDate())+"T"+m00(dt.getUTCHours())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCMinutes())+":"+m00(dt.getUTCSeconds())+"+0000"; s = a.convertToNeutral(s, "date", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"); s = a.convertFromNeutral(s, "date", "short_date"); document.write(s);}</script></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellHeader" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" uniqueID="ms__id17">Part Number</td>
            <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id18">Name</td>
            <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id32">Description</td>
            <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id19">Calculated Quantity</td>
            <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id20">AML Status</td>
            <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id21">Manufacturer</td>
            <td class="cellHeader" uniqueID="ms__id22">Manufacturer Part</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">E000371</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">Part 1</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id25">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id26">Preliminary</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id27">Speer</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id28">RK7D</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">E000371</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">Part 1</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id25">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">Preliminary</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">Ven</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id31">CR00T</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">E000371</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">Part 1</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id25">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">Preliminary</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">Sonic</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id31">ERJ</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">E000371</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">Part 1</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id25">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">Preliminary</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">Comp</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id31">NRCF</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">E000371</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">Part 1</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id25">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">Preliminary</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">Ya</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id31">RC0L</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">E001163</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">82</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">Part 2</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id25">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id26">Preliminary</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id27">Sonic</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id28">E2GX5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">E001163</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">82</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">Part 2</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id25">0</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id29">Preliminary</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id30">Sonic</td>
            <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id31">EGX5</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script><script src="../../javascript/PopupMenu.js"></script></html>
```

Comment: A smaller test-case would be helpful here, there's an awful lot of data there.

Comment: Actually describing how your desired output is different from your current output instead of just an example to dig through would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your XSLT could use a lot of cleanup, but to achieve your desired output, you can replace this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="draw_row_for_item">
  <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id"></xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="sum_of_products" select="$sum_of_products"></xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="part_number" select="$part_number"></xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="part_name" select="$part_name"></xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="part_description" select="$part_description"></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

with this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Relationships/Item[@type='Part AML']">
  <xsl:with-param name="sum_of_products" select="$sum_of_products"></xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="part_number" select="$part_number"></xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="part_name" select="$part_name"></xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="part_description" select="$part_description"></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Modify the last template in the XSLT to be like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="Item[@type='Part AML']">
    <xsl:param name="sum_of_products"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="part_number"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="part_name"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="part_description"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="nonFirstShift" select="3 * (position() != 1)" />
    <tr>
      <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" style="border-left:1px #666666 solid;" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id23">
        <xsl:value-of select="$part_number"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">
        <xsl:value-of select="$part_name"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="24%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id24">
        <xsl:value-of select="$part_description"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id25">
        <xsl:value-of select="$sum_of_products"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="12%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id{26 + $nonFirstShift}">
        <xsl:value-of select="state"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id{27 + $nonFirstShift}">
        <xsl:value-of select="related_id/Item/manufacturer/@keyed_name"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td class="cellSolidRightBottom" width="20%" align="center" uniqueID="ms__id{28 + $nonFirstShift}">
        <xsl:value-of select="related_id/Item/item_number"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

And then you can delete the `draw_row_for_item` template.